# SPI Not working when chip select is connected to ground, works fine when connected to CE 0,1 or 2

Tags: rpi.gpio, spi, config.txt

I am working on MFRC522 sensors. However I need more than 3 SPI Devices. The 3 works fine except when I want to connect chip select to GPIO, It does not work. I tried a single spi device by connecting it to gpio and even as ground but no data is received. Works fine when connected to CE.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just tie Chip Select (CS) to ground. In SPI the CS pin not only tells the receiving device to listen but also synchronizes the communication.
SCK sends pulses to separate each bit. But after powering on the slave IC might be in an undefined state regarding the communication to know it is not in the middle of a message. Thus requires a transition on its CS pin to get the communication right. You can use any GPIO pin for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the chip needs to see its slave select line being asserted to respond.

The solution is to use a GPIO and set it low when you want to address the chip and set it high afterwards.

Just use your own GPIO for slave selects and leave the "official" SPI slave selects for use as general GPIO.